# Subtracting a quantity using SQL in access

Tags: sql

My problem is I am subtracting my quantity from my QOH(Quantity On Hand) and when I run my code I just get back the amount it subtracted. Such as I have 1000 items and I subtract 150 from the QOH the query displays -150. I am also having it subtract them by the ItemID so I have to do something like 100 socks - 50 socks and its giving me -50 cause thats what was subtracted.

Heres my code:

```
SELECT  i.ItemID, p.Quantity - i.QOH AS quantity_Remaining
FROM ITEMS AS i, PKG_ITEMS AS p
WHERE  i.ItemID = p.ItemID
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the datatype for both the columns same?(p.quantity and i.QOH in this case) 
and p.quantity is not zero for the where condition .. please check

Comment: Just checked and both are datatype number and no both my itemIDs are all using a number and they aren't zero.

Comment: SELECT i.ItemID, p.Quantity from ITEMS AS i, PKG_ITEMS AS p WHERE  i.ItemID = p.ItemID
ORDER BY 1; Do this query returns value for p.Quantity

Comment: AWESOME! Got it working thanks so much! Ill mark it as answered! I always get mixed up when trying to subtract in SQL. I always think I have to be subtracting something visually like in most other languages and it screws me up. Thanks so much again!